# Drill: Fix Bugs (Java)

Tags: java

We want to create a "Greeting Counter" that tell us how many times you entered a greeting. Improve the program that takes any number of words in a single line as input, and outputs the number of greetings. Valid greetings to count are "Hi", "Hello" and "Hey". Different cases are allowed. The input ends with -1 on a line alone.

Ex: If the input is:

```
Hi World Hey -1
```

then the output is:

```
Greetings: 2
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GreetCounter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

     Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

     String input = scnr.nextLine();
     int i = 1;
      
      while(!input.equals("-1")) {
         if (input.equals("Hi") || input.equals("Hello") || input.equals("Hey")) {
             i +=0; 
         }
      }
         System.out.print("Greetings: ");
         System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [mre]. Tell us what you expect to happen as well as what's actually happening. This will help us answer your question better.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've revised the question with the code I'm trying but i keep getting infinite loop errors.

Comment: Use `.equals()` to compare strings, not `==`. See the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) for more information.

Comment: I'm still getting infinite loop errors

Comment: You need to call `nextLine()` every loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will work like this:
Enter the sentence
How are you Hello Hey hello
Output will be Greetings : 3

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class Geetings {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    /*taking input from console*/
        String input = null;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line = br.readLine();
        if (line.equals("-1"))
            br.close();
        else
            input = line;   
        /* finding frequency of greeting */
        String[] arr = input.split(" ");
        int counter = 0;
        for (String str : arr) {
            if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("Hi") || str.equalsIgnoreCase("Hello") || str.equalsIgnoreCase("Hey")) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Greetings : "+counter);
    }
}
```